# Check if a product belongs to a specific product category in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, custom-taxonomy

In Woocommerce, I would like to check if a product belongs to the product category "soap".

I am using this code:

```
<?php
    global $woocommerce;
    $items = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart();

        foreach($items as $item => $values) { 
            $_product =  wc_get_product( $values['data']->get_id() );
            $getProductDetail = wc_get_product( $values['product_id'] );
            echo "<b>".$_product->get_title() .'</b>  <br> Quantity: '.$values['quantity'].'<br>'; 
            // $category[] = $item->slug;
            // echo $category[0]->cat_name;
            $categories = $_product->get_categories();
            if(has_term( 'soap',$categories )){
                echo "success";
            }else{

                echo "nope";
            }
        }
?>
```

However I am not able to make it work as I get "nope". I think that this is the part of code where the problem is:

```
$categories = $_product->get_categories();
            if(has_term( 'soap',$categories )){
                echo "success";
            }else{

                echo "nope";
            }
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated:** Here is the correct way to make it work:

```
foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) { 
    // The instance of the WC_Product object
    $_product = $cart_item['data'];
    // Some output
    echo '<b>'.$cart_item['data']->get_title().'</b>  <br>'; 
    echo 'Quantity: '.$cart_item['quantity'].'<br>'; 

    // Check for a specific product category
    if( has_term( 'soap', 'product_cat', ￼$cart_item['product_id'] ) ){
        echo "success";
    } else {
        echo "nope";
    }
}
```

Tested and work.

**Notes:**

- To get the `WC_Product` object from cart items, simply use `$cart_item['data']`
- As product variations doesn't manage product categories or product tags, we get in this case the parent variable product ID that `$cart_item['product_id']` allow… 
  So always use `$cart_item['product_id']` in cart items to target a product category or a product tag.
- Woocommerce Product category is a custom taxonomy, different than Wordpres categories.
- `product_cat` is the taxonomy for product categories to be used with `has_term()` and some other Wordpress functions related to terms.