# Check if a product belong to a category in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I try to check if a product located in the specific category or not, in this case I use the following code that I found in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50425892/check-if-a-product-belongs-to-a-specific-product-category-in-woocommerce) :

```
global $post;
if ( has_term( 'game', 'product_cat', $post->ID ) ) {
echo 'It is working';
}  else {
echo 'it is not working';
}
```

and it doesn't show anything in the category and in other categories I see `it is not working` statement.

Comment: In which file of the active theme you are using this code?

Comment: I use this code to create a shortcode and in the product category related to `game` nothing appears and in other categories `it is not working` appears

Comment: In your shortcode, have you checked that you are getting proper product id `$post->ID`?

Comment: Where you have placed this shortcode? In a page or in a specific file?

Comment: I create a file and named it `short-code.php` and then I require this file in `function.php` and then I use this shortcode in `price.php`

Comment: In your shortcode, have you checked that you are getting proper product id `$post->ID`?

Comment: The issue in your case may be `$post->ID ` is not a product id, but it is the page id.

Comment: yes, I check it and it shows correct id.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228447/discussion-between-momin-iqbal-and-m-sallar-rabiei).